# while adding next row field validation is not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

Input number box requires following validations:

1. Length input box should take upto 3 integer values (decimals not allowed)
2. Height input box should take 3 integer number and decimals upto 2 places
3. Character is not allowed for any input box.

After adding the new row(click to button next of Open New Row) same validation must be work but its not working.newly opened row is not taking validation,so how to make this working either in angular or j query.

```js
var app = angular.module('Calc', []);
 var inputQuantity = [];
    $(function() {
      $(".form-control").each(function(i) {
        inputQuantity[i]=this.defaultValue;
         $(this).data("idx",i); // save this field's index to access later
      });
      $(".form-control").on("keyup", function (e) {
        var $field = $(this),
            val=this.value,
            $thisIndex=parseInt($field.data("idx"),10); // retrieve the index
//        window.console && console.log($field.is(":invalid"));
          //  $field.is(":invalid") is for Safari, it must be the last to not error in IE8
        if (this.validity && this.validity.badInput || isNaN(val) || $field.is(":invalid") ) {
            this.value = inputQuantity[$thisIndex];
            return;
        } 
        if (val.length > Number($field.attr("maxlength"))) {
          val=val.slice(0, 5);
          $field.val(val);
        }
        inputQuantity[$thisIndex]=val;
      });      
    });
app.controller('Calc_Ctrl', function ($scope, $http) {
     $scope.choices = [{id : 'choice1', l2 : 0, b2 : 0}];
     $scope.areas = [{id : 'choice2', total : 0}];

     $scope.addNewChoice = function () {
          var newItemNo = $scope.choices.length + 1;
          $scope.choices.push({
               'id' : 'choice' + newItemNo, l2 : 0, b2 : 0
          });
     };
     $scope.removeChoice = function () {
          var lastItem = $scope.choices.length - 1;
          if (lastItem !== 0) {
               $scope.choices.splice(lastItem);
          }
     };
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="newscript.js"></script>

<body>
  <div ng-app="Calc" ng-controller="Calc_Ctrl">
    <div  data-ng-repeat="choice in choices" class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 bottom-line no-gap">
      <h6>Open New Row {{$index + 1}} 
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default pull-right btn-right-gap  btn-red" aria-label="Left Align"  ng-click="addNewChoice()" style="margin-top: -5px;" id="plus_icon">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        </button>
      </h6> 
      <div class="row walls top-gap">
        <div class="form-group col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">
          <label for="length">Length :</label>
          <input type="number" class="form-control text-red bold" id="length"  ng-model="choice.l2" min="0" max="999" maxlength="6" step="0.00" >
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">
          <label for="height">Height :</label>
          <input type="number" class="form-control text-red bold" id="height"   ng-model="choice.b2" min="0" max="999" maxlength="6" step="0.01">
        </div>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default pull-right btn-red" aria-label="Left Align"  ng-click="removeChoice()" id="minus_icon">
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You are mixing Angular and jQuery together... Not a good thing...

Comment: @Paritosh ,i tried with angular only using ng-maxlength and ng-minlength but its not working so only i used jQuery,but unfortunately still its not working,do u have any idea,please share?